# Android: One layout shows the Action Bar and one doesn't

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, themes, titlebar

First of all here are my two layouts screenshottted:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqHMp.jpg

Both layouts are set to AppTheme style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/colorDivider</item>
</style>
```

Android Studio actually shows them to have NO action bar. However I would prefer to set both to have an action bar.

I also have another style which neither are given:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Here is my manifest by the way:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginPlatformActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginUsernameActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginCharacterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".CharacterSelection" />
</application>
```

I have tried setting the theme for each activity inside the manifest, however this didn't work.

I also heard that by changing the theme is the Android Preview, it doesn't affect the app physically?

Android Preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfXQb.png

Comment: Are you set your activities to extends AppCompatActivity?

Comment: post your activity code here.

Comment: Yes, I was extending Activity. I changed it to AppCompatActivity and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You must extend the class by AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that both activities which you describe extends from AppCompatActivity.

Comment: This should be a comment not in answers.